# Homomorphism from Normalizer

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

While working through Pinter's *A Book of Abstract Algebra*, I encountered the following problem:

> Let $K$ be a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$, and $N = N(K)$ the normalizer of $K$. Let $a \in N$, and suppose the order of $Ka$ in $N/K$ is a power of $p$. Let $S = \langle Ka \rangle$ be the cyclic subgroup of $N/K$ generated by $Ka$. Prove that $N$ has a subgroup $S^*$ such that $S^* / K$ is a $p$-group.

It is hinted that the Correspondence Theorem should be used, i.e. that if $f$ is a homomorphism from $G$ onto $H$ with kernel $K$ and $S$ is a subgroup of $H$ and $S^* = \{x \in G : f(x) \in S\}$, then $S \cong S^*/K$.

---

From this, I would guess that $S^*$ should here be defined as $\{x \in N: f(x) \in S \}$. Following the format above, we would have $f: N \mapsto S$ where $\operatorname{ker}(f) = K$.

**Is this the right setup, and if so how would I define $f$?**

Comment: $f$ is the quotient map from $N$ to $N/K$.

Comment: @Nex thank you so much. Your comment makes perfect sense. Please turn that comment into an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? $N/K$ is a $p'$-group, since $K$ is Sylow. Hence if $Ka$ is a $p$-element, then $Ka=K$, that is $a \in K$. There is no $K \subseteq S^* \subseteq N$, such that $|S^*:K|$ is a non-trivial $p$-power.

Comment: @NickyHekster copied exactly. And yes, what you mention is exactly the point of this section. The goal *is* that we get $Ka = K$ and show $S^* / K$ is trivial in subsequent problems. This is then used to prove the first Sylow Theorem.

Answer (score 3):

As $K$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$, $p$, by definition, doesn't divide $\vert G:K\vert =\vert G\vert /\vert K\vert $. Now $\vert N\vert /\vert K\vert =\vert N/K\vert $ divides $\vert G:K\vert $ and so $p$ can't divide $\vert N/K\vert $ either. So there is no element with order a power of $p$ in $N/K$, except $\bar{1}$.
So if $\bar{a}\in N/K$ (where $\bar{a}$ shall denote the class $Ka$, as for $\bar{1}$ above) has as order a power of $p$, for an $a\in N$, then $\bar{a}=\bar{1}$, which means $a\in K$.

Note that here can be several $p$-Sylow subgroups for a given group $G$ and a given $p$, but they are all conjugate (and thus isomorphic) to each other (which is actually one of the Sylow theorems). Hope this helps.